# Removes only the last list item bug React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

So I have a list of items being generated and for some reason whenever I try to remove one (the handleDelete callback onClick function), it always removes the last item. I added keys to each item so I'm not sure why it's not working. I would appreciate any insight!

Places to look:

handleDelete()

Keys to Box element of each list item

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "0a",
    name: "Jbone",
    tag: "@jbone",
    timePosted: "5 min",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit.",
  },
  {
    id: "1b",
    name: "T",
    tag: "@t",
    timePosted: "5 min",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit.",
  },
  {
    id: "2c",
    name: "W",
    tag: "@w",
    timePosted: "5 min",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit.",
  },
  {
    id: "3d",
    name: "X",
    tag: "@x",
    timePosted: "5 min",
    content:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit.",
  },
];

const HeaderComponent = ({ name, tag, time }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <strong>{name}</strong>{" "}
      <Typography component="span" variant="body2">
        {tag} <span>&#183;</span> {time}
      </Typography>
    </>
  );
};

const AlignItemsList = ({ feed, setFeed }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    // setFeed(prevFeed => {
    //   const feed = prevFeed.filter(post => post.key !== key)
    //   return feed;
    // })
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popover" : undefined;

  return feed.map((post) => {
    // console.log(post.key)
    return (
      <Box key={post.id}>
        <ListItem
          alignItems="flex-start"
          secondaryAction={
            <ListItemText
              primary={
                <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
                  <MoreHorizIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          }
        >
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText
            primary={
              <HeaderComponent
                name={post.name}
                tag={post.tag}
                time={post.timePosted}
              />
            }
            secondary={
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography
                  sx={{ display: "inline" }}
                  component="span"
                  variant="body2"
                  color="text.primary"
                >
                  {post.content}
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
          />
          <Popover
            id={id}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left",
            }}
          >
            <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>
              <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(post.id)}>Delete</Button>
            </Typography>
          </Popover>
        </ListItem>
        <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
      </Box>
    );
  });
};

const PostFeed: React.FC = () => {
  const [inputStr, setInputStr] = useState("");
  const [feed, setFeed] = useState<any>(data);
  const [showPicker, setShowPicker] = useState(false);

  const onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    setInputStr((prevInput) => prevInput + emojiObject.emoji);
    setShowPicker(false);
  };

  const onPostClick = () => {
    if (inputStr != "") {
      setFeed((prevFeed) => {
        return [
          ...prevFeed,
          {
            id: `${prevFeed.length}` + "xz",
            name: "Jasper",
            tag: "@friendlyghost",
            timePosted: "10 min",
            content: inputStr,
          },
        ];
      });
      setInputStr("");
    }
  };

  const handleKeypress = (e) => {
    //it triggers by pressing the enter key
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      onPostClick();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Paper style={{ height: "12em", paddingTop: "4em" }}>
        <Container>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: "2em" }}>
            <Avatar style={{ marginRight: "1em" }} />
            <input
              style={{ outline: "none", border: "none", width: "100%" }}
              placeholder="add a post here..."
              value={inputStr}
              onChange={(e) => setInputStr(e.target.value)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => handleKeypress(e)}
            />
          </Box>
          <Divider />
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              marginTop: ".5em",
            }}
          >
            <SentimentSatisfiedAltOutlinedIcon
              onClick={() => setShowPicker((val) => !val)}
            />
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => onPostClick()}
              disabled={inputStr === ""}
            >
              Post
            </Button>
          </div>
          {showPicker && (
            <Picker
              pickerStyle={{ width: "100%" }}
              onEmojiClick={onEmojiClick}
            />
          )}
          <Box sx={{ marginTop: "6em" }}>
            <List sx={{ bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
              <AlignItemsList feed={feed} setFeed={setFeed} />
            </List>
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
};

export default PostFeed;
```

Comment: `post.key !== key` maybe you meant `post.id !== id`?

Comment: Appears to be a typo, your data has no `key` property. `prevFeed.filter(post => post.key !== key)` should be `prevFeed.filter(post => post.id !== id)`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo. Cheers.

Comment: So the property used to be called key so that's why it's there. I commented out the code because I wanted to see if the correct post id is being sent in the handleDelete callback and it's not. I keep getting the last post id regardless of the post I click.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the *actual* code you've an issue with? If you can, please try to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we can inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
  const handleDelete = (key) => {
    console.log(key);
    setFeed(prevFeed => {
      const feed = prevFeed.filter(post => post.key !== key)
      return feed;
    })
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
```

but better than sending `setFeed` fn it's make callback like this `onDelete={handleDelete}`

```
<AlignItemsList feed={feed} onDelete={handleDelete} />
```

and of course move code for delete from `AlignItemsList` to parent.

EDIT
part of code:

```
  return feed.map((post) => {
    const { id, content, name, tag, timePosted } = post;
    return (
      <Box key={id}>
        <ListItem
          alignItems="flex-start"
          secondaryAction={
            <ListItemText
              primary={
                <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
                  <MoreHorizIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            />
          }
        >
          <ListItemAvatar>
            <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg" />
          </ListItemAvatar>
          <ListItemText
            primary={
              <HeaderComponent
                name={name}
                tag={tag}
                time={timePosted}
              />
            }
            secondary={
              <React.Fragment>
                <Typography
                  sx={{ display: "inline" }}
                  component="span"
                  variant="body2"
                  color="text.primary"
                >
                  {content}
                </Typography>
              </React.Fragment>
            }
          />
          <Popover
            id={id}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left",
            }}
          >
            <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>
              <Button onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}>Delete</Button>
            </Typography>
          </Popover>
        </ListItem>
        <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
      </Box>
    );
  });
```

Comment: So the id property used to be called key so I commented that out for now. The problem still occurs when I console.log the id in the handleDelete callback function. I keep getting the id of the last post.